# Get all select > options where value meets condition

Tags: jquery, html-select

Working on a jQuery script where I need to be able to access any options in a select that have a value that is greater than or equal to a given amount (depending on user input).

The only problem is that the values in the `<option>`s are string literals. I can't change this as it would affect other areas of the program, so I need a way to parse the values to int, and then check them against the condition.

I know that jQuery/JavaScript has a ParseInt() method, but I'm relatively new to scripting and not sure how the syntax for this would have to look. From a look around online, I've seen that `$.map` might be the solution, but I'm still not sure how it would have to be coded.

For example:

```
<select>
    <option value="500">Lower Limit</option>
    <option value="1000">Middle Limit</option>
    <option value="1500">Upper Limit</option>
</select>
```

With something like this, I could be looking to access all of the options with a value >= 1000

Any help with this would be great. Thanks in advance.

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `filter()`:

```
var min = 1000; // from user input
var $options = $('select option').filter(function() {
    return parseInt(this.value, 10) >= min;
});

// use $options here...
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this. Do you mind explaining a couple of things to me regarding your code?

Comment: Sure, what specifically?

Comment: I've just figured out the 'prop' method you used, so that's ok. What is the purpose of the literal constant as the second parameter of `ParseInt`? Thanks

Comment: That's the `radix`, used to determine the base of the numerical system you want to use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Sorry, just coming back to this as I've had some unexpected behaviour following the use of this function. I think some of it might stem from the use of 'this.value'. When I try to enter this again now, the 'value' attribute does not appear in the list. Is there something that should be used instead?

Comment: Nope, `value` is a property which should always exist on the element. Can you show an example of the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=yeoUALsHU4 Try it here, simplified program but same issue. Try and use the selected options for anything (e.g. disabling) and nothing happens.

Comment: Your fiddle was missing jQuery, but seems to work fine when you add it (click the 'Javascript' box then choose jQuery from the frameworks dropdown). Add `console.log(this.value)` within the `each()` and you'll see in the console the values of 600 and higher being listed:

Comment: Thanks, it works on the Fiddle now. I've just tried to put the same in an `alert` on my project to get some confirmation that the elements were being accessed and nothing has appeared. Does this mean I have a more fundamental option in terms of my element selection??

Comment: In that case it sounds like you have an error elsewhere in your code. Check the console